# input a max characters into a textbox when a value is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How can I only allow a certain amount of characters be entered into a `TextBox` when a value is selected from a `ComboBox`?  New to c#.

```
private void cbType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)     

     try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();


            while (myReader.Read())
            {


                string sType = myReader.ToString();

                if (sType == "Low")
                {

                    int Value = 50;
                }

                else if (sType == "Medium")
                {
                    int Value = 100;
                }

                else if (sType == "High")
                {
                    int Value = 150;
                }

                txtDesc.MaxLength = (int)sType.Value;

            }
```

Comment: hint: Handle the keydown event of the textbox

Comment: Combobox or textbox? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, I believe that you're looking for:

```
yourTextBox.MaxLengh = (int)yourComboBox.Value;
```

Where yourTextBox and yourComboBox are objects you're displaying on your window.

I haven't checked if this is 100% right, but it's definitely something like that.

---

**Edit after update:**

I've understood your first question a bit wrong for the first time. Here is solution you're probably looking for:

```
// ...
string sType = myReader.ToString();

switch(sType){
    case "Low": txtDesc.MaxLength= 50; break;
    case "Medium": txtDesc.MaxLength= 100; break;
    case "High": txtDesc.MaxLength= 150; break;
}

// ...
```

Comment: ok so in the combo box I have High or low. High = 20, low =10

Comment: I do not understand what you mean... Is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: sorry, I mean when selects High, I need textbox to only allow 20 characters

Comment: thanks, this is what I am looking for but Max length is staying set to 0

Comment: I don't know about that, it should work. I've changed the solution and took out the usage of variable and instead put in direct assignment to MaxLength. This should work correctly or you're not using it like I've  written here. You could add `txtDesc.Refresh();` after `switch statement` to ensure that GUI updates. But if that is all you do in the event, it's called automatically when event method executes.

Comment: using breakpoint, it does not jump into the case "Low", etc. don't know why

Comment: What is assigned to sType and what exactly is myReader? I hope you know what you're doing; in this example I've modified what you've provided. If you want to get value from ComboBox, you'll probably have to use different variable.

Comment: Thanks I had left out the following:myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        if(myReader.Read())
        {
            string sType = myReader["name_of_field"].ToString();

Comment: Okay, if that works for you, I'm glad to be helpful to you. But note, if you want to use value selected from ComboBox, you have to reference its variable, like `myComboBox.SelectedValue` and use it like I used `sType` in the provided solution. I'm just mentioning this because that is what you've asked in first question.